# Visual Studio 2013 Asp.net Razor v3 website unable to host to IIS windows 7.5

Tags: iis, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to host a asp.net razor v3 website to IIS, but it is not working. I tried multiple options including first creating the website then publishing to IIS, or directly creating a new website under IIS using visual studio 2013. It gives me HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Methods to reproduce Error:
Option 1
1) Create a new asp.net web site (razor v3) in visual 2013, and click publish to publish to a directory. Then, add that directory as a website in IIS.

Option 2
1) On the new website window, in visual studio 2013, go to browse and select IIS, and create a  virtual directory directory under IIS to save the site.

Then, go to the browser and try to access the hosted site: localhost/sitename, it always produces some kind of errors. Like 503. What am I missing? Please help, looks like I am missing some steps or some configuration changes.

Also, I am trying this with the default razor v3 webiste content and without modifying anything. So, I have not touched any files or anything, I am just trying to upload to IIS.

Comment: This is usually due to a misconfiguration between your web's config and how the site is being accessed. One thing to try is creating a new integrated asp.net app pool in iis with it's account set to LocalService and set your web application to use the new app pool. It may reveal a more clear message.

Comment: I searched all around on the web and did not find any information on hosting Asp.net Razor Webpages on IIS, they have information on MVC and Asp.net Webforms, but not on IIS razor pages.

Comment: As I said, I did not modify anything. I just added the application under IIS after I published the default generated. It works fine when you run through visual studio, it just does not run when you upload it to IIS.

Comment: The problem may not lie in your app. There could have been 100's of clicks and checks made in IIS that would cause this error to be displayed. That is why I suggested to create a new app pool targeting the same .net framework you are working with in development. The only other thing I could suggest without more specific details is to enable advanced logging so you can get to more specific details as to what is not configured correctly. http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Looks like my question should be: How do you host Asp.net Razor Webpages v3 or v2 websites on local IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer I found was that for some reason you must use the IIS Express 8.5 to test/host that site.

Even the installations on the fresh copies of Windows with Full IIS prior to version 8 did not work on my test machines.